# Looking for stats/probability practice problems with data and solutions

Tags: r, probability, self-study, references, excel

I am looking for a self-study site on the web that will allow me to verify my understanding of some basic probability and stats concepts and operations.

What I would like is a site with data and problems (along with the solutions) that I could use to practice my skills (such as regression methods/analysis, pairwise t-tests, computation and interpretation of confidence intervals, etc.). I've seen workbooks like this, but the data is not available for me to import into R or Excel.

Surely there must be a site like this on the internet, arranged by topics for study, but somehow I have not been able to find it. Also, if anyone knows of a good workbook that comes with data (on CD or via web) I'd be interested in it too.

I'll be using R and Excel - so pointers to these would be great too.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be made CW?

Comment: I'm still somewhat new to this site .. what does it mean to make something a Community Wiki (question?) ? I understand it doesn't contribute to reputation(?) but other than that, does it matter? (I have been reading the FAQ, but some of the mechanics of this site are still a bit unclear to me). Thanks.

Comment: It's just that there might not be a "best" or good response, and that arguments can be made arbitrarily subjective. It doesn't mean, however, that the question in not interesting *per se*; asker/users won't earn rep from it, but they still get the opportunity to gain badges and the like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **[Statistics topic area on Wikiversity](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Statistics)** is worth a *look*. It's got a long way to go before it's a comprehensive stand-alone syllabus, to be honest, but *some* of the Courses are more advanced than others, and when there's not much material as yet there are often links to free online resources.

Answer (score 6):

If you are interested in Statistical Machine Learning, which seems to be THE thing these days, [Tibshirani, Hastie, and Friedman's book](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) is an invaluable resource. It is the latest edition and has a self contained website devoted to it.

Answer (score 4):

I realise that this may not be what you are looking for, but R core and all packages come with data sets on which to practice the functionalities in each package. Many of these data sets are quite famous, and often a link is given to the paper in which the data are described. You could use these datasets in R and then after you finish your analysis look at what the authors of the paper did with the same data.

That being said, its rare for there to be a right answer in any real data analysis problem, mostly one learns by realising that your techniques were not appropriate and re-iterating until one reaches some level of statisfaction. Obviosuly this is a moving target though, as your skills increase an older dataset may yield new insights.

Comment: In line with your response, the [HSAUR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HSAUR/index.html) textbook deserves some attention.

Comment: @chl thats totally correct, i'd forgotten about that. The books on CRAN generally are often quite good.